# I can't upload image to strapi

Tags: javascript, svelte, strapi

I am trying to upload image to `strapi`, but I am getting error 400 ,this my code :
I guess the error because it can't read the file input I am not sure

```html
<script>

import axios from "axios";
// const files = document.getElementById('file');
let formData = new FormData();
var file = document.querySelector('form');

  let handleUpload = () => {

 // You should have a server side REST API 
 axios.post('http://localhost:1337/upload',
     formData,{ 
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        }
      ).then(function () {
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
      })
      .catch(function () {
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
      });
  };

</script> 

<div class="card" >
  <form id="myFrom" >
    <input
      type="file"
  id="image"
      name="file"
      alt="image"
    />
    <br />
    <button type="submit"on:click={handleUpload()}>Send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

[this there showing in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oddES.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here :

```html
<button type="submit"on:click={handleUpload()}>Send</button>
```

You call `handleUpload()` instead of a reference. `handleUpload()` is called when the button is mounted, instead of when the button is clicked.

You must remove the `()`

```html
<button type="submit"on:click={handleUpload}>Send</button>
```

Comment: even when i remove () , still the same